# Socket IO client id

Tags: mongodb, flutter, socket.io

I am trying to make a chat app, that users can send messages privately to each other. I am using Socketio package in Nodejs and flutter for the Frontend. I am using io.to(clientid).emit function to send messages between users.

I am facing a problem when a user closes the app or disconnect, next time when they connect, SocketIO generates a new id for them so I have to handle that and make changes into database(Mongodb) and refresh users list id in Frontend.

Is there any way that I can have only one unique id for each users device so each users can uses that id and send messages through SocketIO

Comment: you should consider letting people register for an account

Comment: I already added user sign up and log in. I am handling those in another Node js server that is connected to my Mongodb database

Comment: Then you should try emitting a token in a channel like #auth